# Show a selected amount of simple products on configurable

Tags: configurable-product, filter, simple-product

At the moment I am showing associated simple products on a tab on the configurable product which works perfectly with the following code:

```
if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"): ?>
<?php $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product); ?>
<?php $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions()->addAttributeToSort('Price', 'asc'); ?>
```

I then echo about 3 pieces of information from the simple products like:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($simple_product->getPrice()) ?>
```

this is contained inside a table and that is the reason I am dropping in and out of php.

What I want to do now is limit the amount of simple products that is displayed to about 5 as in some cases there are over 20.

I then want a link/button saying show more which will show the remaining products if the person wishes to do so.

Thank you :)

Comment: Do you want the "show more" yo load a new page or to slide down? Do you want to use ajax to load products or just hide them until the show more is click?

Comment: I want them to load under the already loaded products

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736786/jquery-load-first-3-elements-click-load-more-to-display-next-5-elements

Comment: I have had a look and it is totally different to what I am doing :) Unless you can advise of where I am going wrong?

Comment: I want to hide everything below the 5th product/table

Comment: Can you add the html markup that you are using to display the product

Comment: There is none. this pulls the information from the simple product and displays it on the page.

Comment: Are you using a loop (i.e foreach) to display the products?

Comment: I'm not using anything, i'm only echo'ing specific attributes

Comment: Can you add a screen shot, so I can have a better idea of what you are trying to do

Comment: I got the initial code from here: http://www.tripleginteractive.com/blog/magento/magento-configurable-products-simple-product-data/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul id="myList">

if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):
    $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
    $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
    foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){
        echo '<li>' . $simple_product->getSku() . " - " . $simple_product->getName() . " - " . Mage::helper('core')->currency($simple_product->getPrice()) . '</li>';
    }
endif;

</ul>
<div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
```

Then follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736786/jquery-load-first-3-elements-click-load-more-to-display-next-5-elements

Comment: Im nearly there thank you. I feel like a complete idiot for not giving the correct information. The only problem i am having now is that i want to load all and close with one button, is it possible? `$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $("#myList li").size();
    x=5;
    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+99 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
        $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-99<0) ? 5 : x-5;
        $('#myList li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
    });
});`